# Nexus 3: raw proxy repository fails for url containing %

Tags: proxy, nexus, sonatype

I've set up a raw proxy for http://downloads.sourceforge.net called http.downloads.sourceforge.net in Nexus OSS 3.11.
It works fine for most URL, e.g.

http://nexus:8081/repository/http.downloads.sourceforge.net/libpng/zlib/1.2.11/zlib-1.2.11.tar.xz

but fails with *ERROR 400: Invalid repository path.*
for an URL containing percentage signs, e.g.
     http://nexus:8081/repository/http.downloads.sourceforge.net/infozip/UnZip%206.x%20%28latest%29/UnZip%206.0/unzip60.tar.gz

The original URL http://downloads.sourceforge.net/infozip/UnZip%206.x%20%28latest%29/UnZip%206.0/unzip60.tar.gz works fine, tested it with wget.

Is this a problem within Nexus or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a bug in NXRM.  I've created https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-18610 to hopefully get it fixed or responded to.

Comment: Thanks for creating the bug report! I wasn't sure if I wasn't doing something stupid here - Nexus is quite new for me.

Comment: @JoergAlbert NP, there is also a community site community.sonatype.com where you can ask Qs if you get stuck.  SO users can prefer SO but all "nexus" focused over there=)

Comment: This issue still exists in current latest version 3.29.0-02